# Cancel Swift Timer From Another Function

Tags: swift

I am using a Swift Timer library found [here](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyTimer). It allows you to run a timer and then stop it using the following syntax:

```
Timer.every(5.seconds) { (timer: Timer) in
    // do something

    if finished {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

I am trying to have the timer start and then have the option of the timer being cancelled from another function but I can't figure out how to reference the timer that is counting down from another function. I have tried doing something like this but it throws the following error:

> Static member `every` cannot be used on instance of type Timer

```
   var countTimer = Timer()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            initNotificationSetupCheck()

           countTimer.every(5.seconds) { //error here

        }

     func stopTimer() {

           countTimer.invalidate()

           }
```

Comment: it seems that every is a static member, therefore, you'll need a static method to call this. why not use scheduledTimer method which is instance type? for example: Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true). by the way according to the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer I don't see the every method. basically, scheduledTimer will create a timer and schedule it to run on a time interval. in order to stop the timer, you will have to call invalidate() on your instance var :)

Comment: the every method is from the library that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you were to use a mixture of both, but instead of creating an instance of Timer, assign the timer from inside the closure to your member variable like:

```
var countTimer: Timer
Timer.each(5.seconds) { timer in
    countTimer = timer
    //rest of code
}
```

Then you can invalidate the timer outside of the closure if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self,
                                  selector: #selector(self.eventForTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

for cancelling timer

```
func cancelTimer() {
    self.timer.invalidate()
}
```